# How do I send a POST request in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have this code which I am attempting to convert to RestSharp. I have removed the using blocks to condense it for clarity.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using RestSharp;

string GetResponse(string url,string data)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    if (stream == null) return string.Empty;
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I tried something to the order of:

```
string GetResponse(string url, string data)
{
    var client = new RestClient(url);
    var request = new RestRequest("", RestSharp.Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", data);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    return response.Content;
}
```

I can't seem to POST a request using RestSharp, what's the right format to send a POST request in `application/x-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: The java server (that I have no control over) consuming the request is giving me a null pointer exception for the second request. Basically from its perspective the request is somehow different. I'm guessing the only real way to debug this is to look at the first request in wireshark and then try and get the RestSharp version to behave the same way. Was hoping for some quick insight otherwise...

Comment: If you share the null pointer exception message with the stacktrace, it might be possible to offer you some advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out the parameters were all already serialized in the data string. Whereas I needed to add them to the RestSharp request manually.

```
foreach (var pair in data) 
{ 
    request.AddParameter(pair.Key, pair.Value); 
}
```

where data is a Key/Value pair struct